# How can implement grouping in ng-select of Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am implementing multiple select dropdown in my **Angular2** project by following this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/JcG8uO9nIfSGMEKdLf0Y?p=preview). But now i have to show grouping in this multiple select dropdown so how can i implement this? Or is there any other plugin or something like that i can follow.

**Component Html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="selector-form">
    <div class="marTop20">
        <ng-select [options]="options1"
                   [multiple]="multiple1"
                   placeholder="Select multiple"
                   formControlName="selectMultiple"
                   (opened)="onMultipleOpened()"
                   (closed)="onMultipleClosed()"
                   (selected)="onMultipleSelected($event)"
                   (deselected)="onMultipleDeselected($event)">
        </ng-select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Component code in ts file:**

```
export class FilterClientSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    multiple1: boolean = true;
    options1: Array<any> = [];
    selection: Array<string>;
    @ViewChild('preMultiple') preMultiple;
    logMultipleString: string = '';

    constructor() {
        let numOptions = 100;
        let opts = new Array(numOptions);
        for (let i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
            opts[i] = {
                value: i.toString(),
                label: i.toString(),
                groupname:'a'
            };
        }
        this.options1 = opts.slice(0);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = new FormGroup({});
        this.form.addControl('selectMultiple', new FormControl(''));
    }
    private scrollToBottom(elem) {
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

I need the output like the following screen shot:

**Output Page:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is supported natively by ng-select.

https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/grouping

```
<ng-select [items]="accounts"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="name"
           groupBy="country"
           [multiple]="true"
           [hideSelected]="true"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">
    <ng-template ng-optgroup-tmp let-item="item">
        {{item.country || 'Unnamed group'}}
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```