# ng-multiselect-dropdown with option group

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, multi-select, optgroup

I am trying to group my options in ng-multiselect-dropdown. Is there any way, I cannot find any reference. Please see my code as below.
**.html**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select one'" [data]="mutiData" [settings]="multiDataSettings">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**.ts**

```
this.multiData = [
    { id: '1', value: 'A one', 'group':'A' },
    { id: '2', value: 'A two', 'group':'A' },
    { id: '3', value: 'B one', 'group':'B' },
];

this.multiDataSettings = {
    singleSelection: true,
    idField: 'id',
    textField: 'value',
    itemsShowLimit: 1,
    groupBy: "group",
};
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045245/how-to-implement-multiple-select-dropdow-with-grouping-in-angular-2-application ?

Comment: @VishnuPrasad - did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is Angular's very light weight library for Multiselect-dropdwon. It is provide a wide range of features like Group-By, search, custom-search, Virtual-scrolling etc.
You can refer: https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/groupby

#### You can import library using this command:

*npm install angular2-multiselect-dropdown*

#### Import AngularMultiSelectModule into NgModule in app.module.ts:

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';

@NgModule({
  // ...
imports: [
  AngularMultiSelectModule,
]
// ...
});
```

#### Add the following component tag in you template:

```
   <angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
     [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
     (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
     (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
     (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
     (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
   </angular2-multiselect>
```

#### In your component add this code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
dropdownList = [];
selectedItems = [];
dropdownSettings = {};
ngOnInit(){
    this.itemList = [
  { "id": 1, "itemName": "India", "category": "asia" },
  { "id": 2, "itemName": "Singapore", "category": "asia pacific" },
  { "id": 3, "itemName": "Germany", "category": "Europe" },
  { "id": 4, "itemName": "France", "category": "Europe" },
  { "id": 5, "itemName": "South Korea", "category": "asia" },
  { "id": 6, "itemName": "Sweden", "category": "Europe" }
];

this.selectedItems = [
  { "id": 1, "itemName": "India" },
  { "id": 2, "itemName": "Singapore" },
  { "id": 4, "itemName": "Canada" }];
    this.dropdownSettings = { 
                              singleSelection: false, 
                              text:"Select Countries",
                              selectAllText:'Select All',
                              unSelectAllText:'UnSelect All',
                              enableSearchFilter: true,
                              groupBy: "category"
                            };            
}
onItemSelect(item:any){
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.selectedItems);
}
OnItemDeSelect(item:any){
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.selectedItems);
}
onSelectAll(items: any){
    console.log(items);
}
onDeSelectAll(items: any){
    console.log(items);
}
```

}

Let me know if you still having any query. Happy to help.

Comment: Question was regarding - "ng-multiselect-dropdown" and not "angular2-multiselect-dropdown"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so ng-multiselect-dropdown providing this.

If you want to do this anyhow then you can try this instead of **ng-multiselect-dropdown**

```html
<select id="food" name="food" multiple>
  <optgroup label="Fruits">
    <option value="1">Apples</option>
    <option value="3">Bananas</option>
    <option value="4">Peaches</option>
    <option value="5">...</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Vegetables">
    <option value="2">Carrots</option>
    <option value="6">Cucumbers</option>
    <option value="7">...</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Baked Goods">
    <option value="8">Apple Pie</option>
    <option value="9">Chocolate Cake</option>
    <option value="10">...</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Question was regarding - "ng-multiselect-dropdown" and not "angular2-multiselect-dropdown"

Comment: But I didn't mention angular2-multiselect-dropdown anywhere.

Comment: you didn't mention but question is related to ng-multiselect-dropdown right ?